# Сортировка таблицы по полю HIGH_VALUE (тип данных LONG)

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо отсортировать партиции таблицы `(таблица SYS.all_tab_partitions)` по `HIGH_VALUE`, но при обычно ORDER BY выводится следующая ошибка:

```
ORA-00997: неверное использование типа данных LONG
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
```

Можно ли это сделать без отдельных процедур и временных таблиц?

Comment: без временных таблиц - никак.  вам понадобится промежуточная таблица с CLOB-столбцом.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как сделать через временную таблицу, буду пробовать все варианты)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. создать временную таблицу (не обязательно GTT)

```
create global temporary table all_tab_partitions_gtt (
   table_owner        varchar2(128),
   table_name         varchar2(128),
   partition_name     varchar2(128),
   high_value         clob,
   partition_position number
) on commit delete rows;
```

2. загрузить данные во временную таблицу, избавившись от LONG

```
delete all_tab_partitions_gtt;
insert into all_tab_partitions_gtt (
   table_owner,
   table_name,
   partition_name,
   high_value,
   partition_position
) 
select
   table_owner,
   table_name,
   partition_name,
   to_lob(high_value),
   partition_position
from 
   all_tab_partitions
where 
   -- выборка нужных таблиц
   ...
```

3. просмотреть загруженные данные

```
select 
   * 
from 
   all_tab_partitions_gtt 
order by 
   to_char(high_value)
```

Правда, `high_value` хранит не значение, а литерал значения, возможно придётся сначала его сконвертировать в значение нужного типа (напр, динамическим запросом).

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отработало корректно